# c++ stl vector iterator insert segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

```
          std::vector<struct::event>::iterator it;
          std::vector<struct::event>::iterator last=myvector.end();

          for (it=myvector.begin(); it<=last; it++){

            if(mysignal.declination<(*last).declination){

              if (mysignal.declination>=(*it).declination && mysignal.declination<(*(it+1)).declination){
                myvector.insert(it+1, mysignal);
                break;
              }
            }
            if (mysignal.declination>=(*last).declination){
              myvector.push_back(mysignal);
              break;
            }


            }
```

I have a vector called myvector with events that are sorted with the declination. now I want to add mysignal to this vector on the right place. but i always get a seg fault after a few events which refers to: if(mysignal.declination<(*last).declination). I just  can't see what is wrong.

Comment: ok, I understand I cannot use last and I fixed the loop condition. But how can I prevent the vector from overrunning? I mean when I have an event that has a bigger declination than all the events in myvector there will be no (it+1) right? (and this will crash I suppose) so how can get to the pushback line if not using something like >last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, C++ iterators define a half-open interval
(`'[begin()...end())'`), which is what you should probably be
using in most other cases as well.  And although it works with
iterators from a vector, in general, iterators do not support
`<=` (nor `<`); the standard idiom for a loop is:

```
for ( auto current = container.begin();
        current != container.end();
        ++ current ) ...
```

(In the most likely case that you cannot count on C++11, you'll
have to write out the full iterator type, rather than use 
`auto`.  Although `auto` is one of the few things from C++11
that seems to work with VC++11 *and* with recent versions of
g++, so if those are the only targets you're concerned with, and
you can be sure of always having very recent versions, you can
use it.)

Also, if you want to access the last element of the vector in
the loop, `myvector.back()` will return a reference to it.
(`myvector.back()` is undefined behavior if the vector is empty,
but if the vector is empty, you won't enter the loop.)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is wrong, read [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end):

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container.
>   This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.

You can't dereference `end()`, it provides a way of knowing that you have overrun the container, so your loop condition should be `it != myvector.end()`, and `last` is wrong as well.

Comment: ED, the predicate returns some address then?

Comment: @blackmath: No, I should have said "condition".  Your loop condition is including `end()`, but if `it == end()` the loop should exit.

Comment: I know this. but was thinking deeper about what is going on, I guess the end address is garbage or something so it will never get matched. no crash I assume

Comment: @blackmath: What iterator `end()` returns is an implementation detail.  The fact is that dereferencing it produces undefined behavior, so you can't reason intelligently about what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

end() does not refer to the last element in the container, you need to change your condition as follows.

```
for (it=myvector.begin(); it != last; it++){
```

You have other broken logic as well that is dereferencing last that you need to fix.